# Why does a globbed `find` command in Node (execSync) return different results to the CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, exec

Example:

```
╔═ markl@macbook: /var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T
╚═ ♪ tree tmp.7cHYDVc8rX
tmp.7cHYDVc8rX
├── file
└── subdir
    ├── anothersubdir
    │   └── file
    └── file

2 directories, 3 files

╔═ markl@macbook: /var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T
╚═ ♪ find ./**/*/file -type f
./tmp.7cHYDVc8rX/file
./tmp.7cHYDVc8rX/subdir/anothersubdir/file
./tmp.7cHYDVc8rX/subdir/file

╔═ markl@macbook: /var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T
╚═ ♪ node
> require('child_process').execSync("find ./**/*/file -type f").toString()
'./tmp.7cHYDVc8rX/subdir/file\n'
> %

╔═ markl@macbook: /var/folders/xp/n5tbdrrs761ck82qqychcf61ptmq9d/T
╚═ ♪ node -v
v7.9.0
```

You can see there are 3 files I expect it to find (as the CLI does), but in the node repl, it only returns the last file

Comment: Is node using bash v4? The `/**/` feature you're using isn't available in most other shells (or earlier versions of bash). Anyway, why are you using that, since `find` can descend directory trees on its own?

Comment: ah yeah! it was a bash version issue, I only had bash3.2 installed (my default shell is zsh, which worked with the `/**`. Switching the command to `find . -name file -type f` as suggested works. Thanks!!